# Как правильно открыть csv файл, чтобы числа в нем имели числовой формат?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv

with open('csv_file') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
```

При использовании метода csv.reader(file) файл открывается со строковыми значениями чисел. Как правильно открыть csv файл, чтобы на этими "числами" можно было производить математические операции?

Comment: Куда загрузить?

Comment: @Эникейщик Пререформулировал вопрос

Comment: @Agio, попробуйте [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) - он "заточен" для таких вещей...

Comment: Да, лучше использовать ``pandas.read_csv``. А то просто csv нужно разбивать на строчки, потом на отдельные элементы, потом конвертировать, да еще и ловить исключения. Слишком много возни.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) - он идеально подходит для таких задач:

```
In [19]: import pandas as pd

In [20]: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\data.csv')

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [22]: df['a'].sum()
Out[22]: 12

In [23]: df['a'].mean()
Out[23]: 4.0

In [24]: df.sum()
Out[24]:
a    12
b    15
c    18
dtype: int64

In [25]: df.eval("a**2 + 2*b - c")
Out[25]:
0     2
1    20
2    56
dtype: int64
```